# Seeking Irish PostAim (151) AnPost boundaries?

Tags: geospatial, ireland

I’m trying to source a shapefile or equivalent for the postal (sorting offices) in Ireland. The boundaries are used in the [SortIt AnPost online tool](http://www.anpost.ie/AnPost/AnPostDM/Tools/Sort+IT+Tools/Sort+It.htm) to sort mail but I can’t seem to find them for download anywhere and AnPost are not replying to my emails. Can anyone help?